# Developing my first android app! Doesnt run in emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-emulator

I am developing a Mobile app for the first time

Environment : Eclipse Kepler, Java 1.7 Backend : AWS RDS, database type : MySQL

To start with I have created only 1 activity as shown below, I first want it to display "Hello World" on the home screen.

For ref I am showing incase if nyone knows if am making a mistake in writing code :

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.amazon.demo2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/hello_world" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.amazon.demo2;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.*;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {               
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

fragment_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.amazon.demo2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.amazon.demo2.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="134dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</FrameLayout>
```

strings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">Welcome Dear Customer</string>
<string name="hey">Hey</string>
</resources>
```

Now what i am doing is : Run Configurations -> Android Application -> Android -> Project [Set the project to be run] -> Launch Action -> Launch -> com.amazon.demo2.MainActivity -> Apply -> Run

now its giving me the fol error :

```
[2014-08-18 14:42:13 - ShopSystem-Android2] ------------------------------
[2014-08-18 14:42:13 - ShopSystem-Android2] Android Launch!
[2014-08-18 14:42:13 - ShopSystem-Android2] adb is running normally.
[2014-08-18 14:42:13 - ShopSystem-Android2] Performing com.amazon.demo2.MainActivity     activity launch
[2014-08-18 14:42:14 - ShopSystem-Android2] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD     'standard' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2014-08-18 14:42:14 - ShopSystem-Android2] Launching a new emulator with Virtual     Device 'standard'
[2014-08-18 14:43:04 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
[2014-08-18 14:43:04 - Emulator] 
[2014-08-18 14:43:05 - ShopSystem-Android2] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-08-18 14:43:05 - ShopSystem-Android2] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore')     to be launched...
[2014-08-18 14:44:33 - ShopSystem-Android2] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling     'com.amazon.demo2.MainActivity activity launch'!
```

Basically, what I want is to create an app that allows a user to view product and online and place an order. But I am getting all messed up as xplained above. Please help. Thank you

Comment: what is the maximun Version which AVD which you are using will support?

Comment: AVD : Target name : Android 4.3, Platform 4.3, API level 18, CPU/ABI armeabi-v7a

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.amazon.demo2"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >                                       <uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="11"
  android:targetSdkVersion="20" />